# Ajax loop to get data from $.post each second

Tags: php, ajax, linux, loops, progress-bar

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pbo").hide();
    $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress({
        namespace: 'pie_progress',
        size: 100,
        barsize: '4'
    });
    $("#getit").click(function(){
        $.post("process.php",
        {
            yurl: $("#yurl").val()
        },
        function(data,status){
            if(data > 0 ) {
                $('#yurl').hide();
                $('#getit').hide();
                $("#pbo").show();
                $('h1').hide();

                $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress('start');
                $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress('go',data);

            } else {
                $('#yurl').show();
                $('#getit').show();
                $("#pbo").hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

When I click on my `#getit` button, it executes `process.php` and gets the returned data which is in turn passed to `$('.pie_progress').asPieProgress('go',data);`. My progress bar gets updated with that data, but this only seems to happen once. Is there a way to continue making `POST` requests until the data value is 100?

Note: in the process.php I have an php exec which echos the progress each second.

Answer (score 0):

What about put the ajax call inside a function (for example: processTo100) and recall it everytime?

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pbo").hide();
    $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress({
        namespace: 'pie_progress',
        size: 100,
        barsize: '4'
    });
    $("#getit").click(function(){
        processTo100();
    });

    function processTo100() {
        $.post("process.php",
        {
          yurl: $("#yurl").val()
        },
        function(data,status) {
            if(data > 0 ) {
                $('#yurl').hide();
                $('#getit').hide();
                $("#pbo").show();
                $('h1').hide();

                $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress('start');
                $('.pie_progress').asPieProgress('go',data);
                if( parseInt(data) <= 100) {
                    processTo100(); 
                }
            } else {
                $('#yurl').show();
                $('#getit').show();
                $("#pbo").hide();
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: The loop is correct but each time it re-post the the process.php again and again. I wanted the ajax to post one time the process.php and get the echo of the process each second. e.g of my process.php :
 for( $i=1; $i<=100; $i++ )
{
echo $i;
sleep (1);
}